# window.open fails with relative URLs in IE (When using the base tag)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

**Problem**

I'm using the base tag to resolve relative URLs to a specific point in some dynamically generated .html pages.

This works great until I try to use Window.open in javascript. Firefox resolves everything fine, but IE resolves the URL to the displayed URL.

Is there an IE work around for this?

**I'd like to avoid**

Combining the URL with the href in the base tag via Javascript/jQuery. (Unless it's bullet proof. Recognizing the difference between non-relative urls and relative ones, handling the existince of '/' or none '/' when combining, etc...).

Even if you have such a solution. A built in one would be preferred (a matter of formatting my relative URLs to make IE happy?, or whatever).

**Example**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://stackoverflow.com" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    showWindowPopupFullScreen = function(URL) {
        var pageWidth = screen.availWidth;
        var pageHeight = screen.availHeight;
        var popup = window.open(URL, 'Window', 'height=' + pageHeight + ',width=' + pageWidth + ',top=0,left=0,resizable');
        if (window.focus) {
            popup.focus();
        }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="javascript:showWindowPopupFullScreen('users/402706/brandon-boone')">test</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No idea whether this will work - it might or might not, depending on IE's internal workings -  but you could try whether this gets translated properly:

```
<a href="users/402706/brandon-boone" 
   onclick="showWindowPopupFullScreen(this.href)">test</a>
```

Comment: Note that you have to use `this.href`, it will not work with `this.getAttribute('href')`.

Comment: I had similar problem, it works fine in jQuery as well. I've run popup from `$(element).on('click')` handler. Previously I tried `$(this).attr('href')` and had similar problem as Brandon (even though I set <base>). Now it works fine with `this.href`. Thanks Pekka and Roben !